# Can't add apps to "Files & Folders" under Security & Privacy

Tags: macos, security, settings, privacy

[image]

Can't add apps to "Files & Folders" under Security & Privacy, plus/minus buttons are greyed out.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I think this is by design. If you want to explicitly grant a program full disk access, you can use that section to do so (the plus/minus buttons do work there). But I don't believe there's a way to grant ad-hoc folder-specific permissions for an app that hasn't requested them.